# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse query: {"query":

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I am trying to execute the Elasticsearch DSL query in Spark 2.2 and Scala 2.11.8. The version of Elasticsearch is 2.4.4, while the version of Kibana that I use is 4.6.4.

This is the library that I use in Spark:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my code:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .config("es.nodes","localhost")
      .config("es.port",9200)
      .config("es.nodes.wan.only","true")
      .config("es.index.auto.create","true")
      .appName("ES test")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    val myquery = """{"query":
                          {"bool": {
                             "must": [
                                {
                                   "has_child": {
                                       "filter": {
                                          ...
                                       }
                                    }
                                }
                             ]
                          }
                      }}"""

  
   val df = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
      .option("query", myquery)
      .option("pushdown", "true")
      .load("myindex/items")
```

I provided the main corpus of the DSL query. I am getting the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse query: {"query":

Initially, I was thinking that the problem consists in the version of Elasticsearch. As far as I understand from this [GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop), the version 4 of Elasticsearch is not supported.

However, if I run the same code with a simple query, it correctly retrieves records from Elasticsearch.

```
var df = spark.read
              .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
              .option("es.query", "?q=public:*")
              .load("myindex/items")
```

Therefore I assume that the issue is not related to the version, but it's rather related to the way how I represent the query.

This query works fine with cURL, but maybe it should be somehow updated before passing it to Spark?

**Full error stacktrace:**

```
    Previous exception in task: Failed to parse query: {"query":
                         {"bool": {
                           "must": [
                             {
                               "has_child": {
                                 "filter": {
                                   "bool": {
                                     "must": [
                                       {
                                         "term": {
                                           "project": 579
                                         }
                                       },
                                       {
                                         "terms": {
                                           "status": [
                                             0,
                                             1,
                                             2
                                           ]
                                         }
                                       }
                                     ]
                                   }
                                 },
                                 "type": "status"
                               }
                             },
                             {
                               "has_child": {
                                 "filter": {
                                   "bool": {
                                     "must": [
                                       {
                                         "term": {
                                           "project": 579
                                         }
                                       },
                                       {
                                         "terms": {
                                           "entity": [
                                             4634
                                           ]
                                         }
                                       }
                                     ]
                                   }
                                 },
                                 "type": "annotation"
                               }
                             },
                             {
                               "term": {
                                 "project": 579
                               }
                             },
                             {
                               "range": {
                                 "publication_date": {
                                   "gte": "2017/01/01",
                                   "lte": "2017/04/01",
                                   "format": "yyyy/MM/dd"
                                 }
                               }
                             },
                             {
                               "bool": {
                                 "should": [
                                   {
                                     "terms": {
                                       "typology": [
                                         "news",
                                         "blog",
                                         "forum",
                                         "socialnetwork"
                                       ]
                                     }
                                   },
                                   {
                                     "terms": {
                                       "publishing_platform": [
                                         "twitter"
                                       ]
                                     }
                                   }
                                 ]
                               }
                             }
                           ]
                         }}
    org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.query.QueryUtils.parseQuery(QueryUtils.java:59)
    org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createReader(RestService.java:417)
    org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDDIterator.reader$lzycompute(AbstractEsRDDIterator.scala:49)
    org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDDIterator.reader(AbstractEsRDDIterator.scala:42)
    org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDDIterator.hasNext(AbstractEsRDDIterator.scala:61)
    scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.invokeListeners(TaskContextImpl.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18/01/22 21:43:12 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Failed to parse query: {"query":
```

and this one:

```
8/01/22 21:47:40 WARN ScalaRowValueReader: Field 'cluster' is backed by an array but the associated Spark Schema does not reflect this;
              (use es.read.field.as.array.include/exclude) 
18/01/22 21:47:40 WARN ScalaRowValueReader: Field 'project' is backed by an array but the associated Spark Schema does not reflect this;
              (use es.read.field.as.array.include/exclude) 
18/01/22 21:47:40 WARN ScalaRowValueReader: Field 'client' is backed by an array but the associated Spark Schema does not reflect this;
              (use es.read.field.as.array.include/exclude) 

18/01/22 21:47:40 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
scala.MatchError: Buffer(13473953) (of class scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JListWrapper)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:379)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18/01/22 21:47:40 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): scala.MatchError: Buffer(13473953) (of class scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JListWrapper)
```

Comment: Markus, could you provide full exception details including stack trace? I think the important question is whether this query is reject by the ES node itself or by the client-side wrapper.

Comment: @SergGr: I posted the whole error stacktrace. I think that the key is `Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries`. But how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the error says

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (':' (code 58)):
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@76aeea7a; line: 2, column: 33]
```

and if you look at your `query`

```
val myquery = """{"query":
                      "bool": {
```

you'll see that this probably maps to the `:` just after `"bool"` and obviously what you have is an invalid JSON. To make it clear I just re-format it as

```
{"query": "bool": { ...
```

Most probably you forgot `{` after "query" and the matching `}` at the end. Compare this to an example at [official docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
```

Comment: I added `{` and `}`, but anyway I get the error. Now it's different. Please see the error.

Comment: Thanks. I think that I am now closer to the solution. I get now warnings related to the schema: `18/01/22 21:47:40 WARN ScalaRowValueReader: Field 'cluster' is backed by an array but the associated Spark Schema does not reflect this; (use es.read.field.as.array.include/exclude) `

Comment: I don't think that changing a question to a totally different (and most probably unrelated) error after the previous one was solved is a fair deal. If you have new error, you should create a new question. And also you should investigate it first yourself. And by the way it is really hard to answer a question when the only time 'cluster` is mentioned in the question is in the error message.

Comment: It is related to this issue `https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/1058`. I would like to post more details of the error, but the connector does not return more details.

Comment: @Markus, sorry this is a totally different error and you really should create a new question for it. I'm going to stop answering you here because the original problem has been solved (although you didn't bother to accept it).