# WARN ScalaRowValueReader: Field 'client' is backed by an array but the associated Spark Schema does not reflect this

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

This question is the continuation of [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48389449/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-parse-query-query/48389947?noredirect=1#comment83767917_48389947).

I am trying to execute the Elasticsearch DSL query in Spark 2.2 and Scala 2.11.8. The version of Elasticsearch if 2.4.4. This is the library that I use in Spark:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my current code:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .config("es.nodes","localhost")
      .config("es.port",9200)
      .config("es.nodes.wan.only","true")
      .config("es.index.auto.create","true")
      .config("es.read.field.as.array.include","true")
      .appName("ES test")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    val myquery = """{"query":
                          {"bool": {
                             "must": [
                                {
                                   "has_child": {
                                       "filter": {
                                          ...
                                       }
                                    }
                                }
                             ]
                          }
                      }}"""


   val df = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
      .option("query", myquery)
      .option("pushdown", "true")
      .load("myindex/items")
      .select("test_user", "test_reply")
```

The issue that I get seems to be related to this one: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/1058
But it's not clear how to deal with it.

I get a lot of warnings:

```
18/01/22 22:01:44 WARN ScalaRowValueReader: Field 'author' is backed by an array but the associated Spark Schema does not reflect this;
              (use es.read.field.as.array.include/exclude) 
18/01/22 22:01:44 WARN ScalaRowValueReader: Field 'client' is backed by an array but the associated Spark Schema does not reflect this;
              (use es.read.field.as.array.include/exclude) 
18/01/22 22:01:44 WARN ScalaRowValueReader: Field 'project' is backed by an array but the associated Spark Schema does not reflect this;
              (use es.read.field.as.array.include/exclude)
```

and after that I've got a error

```
18/01/22 22:01:44 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
scala.MatchError: Buffer(13473953) (of class scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JListWrapper)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:379)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18/01/22 22:01:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): scala.MatchError: Buffer(13473953) (of class scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JListWrapper)
```

Then, `df.count()` works well, and `df.printSchema()` returns this result:

```
root
 |-- test_user: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test_reply: string (nullable = true)
```

What do these warnings mean and how to avoid them?

Also, if I don't not use `select`, I get this error:

```
ala.MatchError: Buffer(13473953) (of class scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JListWrapper)
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try replacing the below statement

```
  .config("es.read.field.as.array.include","true")
```

with

```
  .config("es.read.field.as.array.include","author,client,project")
```

"es.read.field.as.array.include" expects all the array fields that need to be included.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/mapping.html#mapping-multi-values